# Check if a variable name is being used in the current method

Tags: objective-c, variables, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to check if a variable name is already defined. **I don't care if it is equal to `nil` or not.** I would use this in a macro that defines a variable if it is not yet defined. But if it is defined, the macro would just set the variable rather than redefining it (which actually prevents the compiler from building).

```
#define newAnimation()\
if (/* variableName is being used */) {\
    anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];\
} else {\
    CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];\
}
```

I would then use the macro like so.

```
newAnimation();
anim.keyPath = @"position.x";
anim.toValue = @10;
[self.namedSubview addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];

newAnimation();
anim.keyPath = @"position.y";
anim.toValue = @50;
[self.otherSubview addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

**Note:** The part with the macro is just my use case for this question. Your answer should work within a method.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your larger goal?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I just clarified.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you not know if a variable has been declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a new inner scope from which you can declare non-conflicting identifiers.  This is why it's always a good idea to wrap your identifier-declaring macros in a single do-while block, or simply a block.  For example, you can change your macro to accept a code block and still keep consecutive invocations from conflicting with each other:

```
#define CFICreateAnimationInScope(BLOCK) { \
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animation]; \
BLOCK \
} \

void f() {
    CFICreateAnimationInScope({
        anim.keyPath = @"position.x";
        anim.toValue = @10;
    });

    CFICreateAnimationInScope({
        anim.keyPath = @"position.y";
        anim.toValue = @50;
    });
}
```

Beyond that, there's actually using a function-like macro (you seem to be confusing macros and C functions from the looks of that pair of empty parens) combined with the scoping changes above to make little animation factories.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor doesn't have information about variables and their names. Outside of its own limited control syntax, it is purely replacement of one bit of text with another, which is *then* passed on to the ObjC parser.

You can't fill in `/* variableName is being used */` with anything to get the effect you're describing.